# Upsizing Wordpress featured image thumbnail / Always convert GIF to JPG

Tags: image, wordpress, thumbnails

This one's a bit of a two-parter, as either could solve my problem.

**Upsizing featured image when selected image smaller than specified thumbnail size**

If a file is uploaded that's smaller than the smallest set thumbnail size - such as a 100x100 image when the thumbnail size is 150x150, Wordpress doesn't force upsize. Is there any way that I can force an upsize, other than using an external source like Imagemagick?

**Convert uploaded GIF to JPG in every instance**

An alternative to forcing an upsize would be to create a JPG alternative to any uploaded GIF file. Right now, GIFs larger than the thumbnail size - such as a 200x200 GIF when the thumbnail size is 150x150 - automatically have a static JPG thumbnail generated.

**I'm generating thumbnails programmatically with**:

```
// Inserts metadata and creates thumbnails for uploaded file
$attach_id = wp_insert_attachment($attachmentMeta, $newFile, $post_id);
$attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata($attach_id, $newFile);
wp_update_attachment_metadata($attach_id, $attach_data);

// Adds the thumbnail to the post
update_post_meta($post_id, '_thumbnail_id', $attach_id);
```

While I could do all of this with Imagemagick, I'd prefer to use Wordpress's own capabilities to get it done. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

As of Wordpress 3.6, I don't believe there is a built-in method to "upsize" an input image so that it fits/fills the requested thumbnail size in the case where the source image is too small.

Downsizing is simple, however. Anyone seeking a solution to this issue may know by now that many users seem to suggest/confuse "add_image_size" as the appropriate solution for this type of issue. It is not the *entire* solution.

It's important to note that if either the width or height of the source image is less than either predefined thumbnail/image-size dimension (i.e., dimensions specified via add_image_size or via the settings), then WP will return original source image instead of a thumbnail. Obviously this can be frustrating.

Many other users have suggested just using CSS to achieve the desired results; e.g., to force a minimum width or height. Although CSS will work in many situations, it won't work in *every* situation, especially in cases where you're dealing with fluid or responsive layouts.

Below is a rough, untested filter used to force a thumbnail to always fit the desired dimensions. Drop this in your functions.php and it will also require [timthumb.php](http://code.google.com/p/timthumb/%20timthumb.php) be available in your theme. You'll likely need to modify it to fit your specific situation, and perhaps it could be improved in several ways.

```
function my_image_downsize($src_data, $thumbnail_id, $size) {
    static $omit = false;
    global $_wp_additional_image_sizes;

    if($omit) {
        return $src_data;
    }

    $omit = true;

    $thumbnail_src_data = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumbnail_id, $size);

    $img_url = $thumbnail_src_data[0];
    $width = $thumbnail_src_data[1];
    $height = $thumbnail_src_data[2];

    if(is_string($size) && isset($_wp_additional_image_sizes[$size]) && ($width < $_wp_additional_image_sizes[$size]['width'] || $height < $_wp_additional_image_sizes[$size]['height'])) {
        // "Upsize" the image as needed, to meet the minimum dimension of the thumbnail.
        $width = $_wp_additional_image_sizes[$size]['width'];
        $height = $_wp_additional_image_sizes[$size]['height'];
        $img_url = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/timthumb.php?src='.$img_url.'&w='.$width.'&h='.$height.'&zc=2&cc=000000'; // TODO: replace timthumb with WP's native media class
    } else {
        $omit = false;
        return $src_data;
    }

    $omit = false;

    return array($img_url, $width, $height);
}
add_filter('image_downsize', 'my_image_downsize', 10, 3);
```